# Read Response body in retrofit2

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

I am accessing webservice API using retrofit2. The response from API is in JSON Format.

JSONResponseImage

[image]

In retrofit my client is making successful connection with API but I want to access "statusMessage": "Email Address already exists" which is sent by webservice. I have tried couple of things but no success.

```
public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
       switch(response.code()) {
          case 409:
             Log.e("TAG", "1: " +response.raw());                         
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "email already Registered",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             break;
       }
    }
}
```

seeImageLog

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `User` class

```
private Integer statusCode;
private String statusMessage;

public Integer getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getStatusMessage() {
return statusMessage;
}

public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
}
```

Now you can access `getStatusMessage()` like `response.body().getStatusMessage();`
NOTE : setters are not necessary, adding getters will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
//This is the status message.
                 String statusMessage = response.body().getStatusMessage();
} else {

                    switch(response.code()){
                        case 409:
                            Log.e("TAG", "1: " +response.raw());                         
                           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "email already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
```

The `User` class:

```
public class User {

  //No need to declare setStatusMessage as the value shall be set by retrofit automatically. No need to make this as public.
    private String statusMessage;

    public String getStatusMessage() {
    //Return statusMessage declared in User class.
    return statusMessage;

      }
}
```

Comment: There is no method "getStatusMessage()" defined in my project. Where should I define this method?

Comment: If I define this function then still its not working. Because, you are not setting "statusMessage" value to user object attribute.
First we have to read value from response, then we can set it to user object attribute.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan In retrofit, the value from response is set automatically to the model object. So, you only need to declare variable `String statusMessage;`  in `User` class. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If this is correct can you please mark this as correct answer?